# Select the students that are enrolled in both the courses

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

[image: Table Defination]

This is the table definition. I want to select the students that are **enrolled in courses (1 and 3)**.

From this dataset the expected output is 'B'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT student_name
FROM <table>
WHERE course_number IN(1,3)
GROUP BY student_name
HAVING COUNT(distinct course_number) = 2;
```

If you have a different dataset (say course_numbers 1,2,3) you can use course_number in (1,2,3) and COUNT(distinct course_number) = 3 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this problem using conditional aggregation based filtering. Firstly, get all the students who are either enrolled `IN(..)` course no `(1, 3)`.

Then, you can use `HAVING` clause to filter out the students having atleast two unique courses subscribed to (which would be 1 and 3 in this case):

```
SELECT student_name 
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE course_number IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY student_name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT course_number) = 2
```

For good performance, you can define the following **Covering Index**: `(course_number, student_name)`